# MySQL three-table join

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have three tables called `Clinic`, `Doctor`, and `Clinic_has_Doctor`. Suppose the two tables `Clinic` and `Doctor` have fields `id` and `name` as follows:

```
Clinic 
+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+

Doctor
+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+
```

And `Clinic_has_Doctor` is a simple table containing mappings between clinics and doctors:

```
Clinic_has_Doctor
+-----------+-----------------+
| Clinic_id | Doctor_id       |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

which expectedly are foreign keys to `Clinic` and `Doctor` IDs. I need to get the list of clinics and the doctors along them. So I would have a table like:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| Clinic_id | Clinic_name  | Doctor_id  | Doctor_name  |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

I haven't done much `JOIN` SQL commands so I couldn't get out of this. Any help?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Most of the questions I have seen on SO are asking for code from others. If you're asking whether I have tried anything, yes I have. But it hasn't worked and to get an answer for that needs a specific question with examples just like I've given. If you know an answer but not willing to show it here, don't bother typing all that advice because I more-or-less know when to ask a question and when to search through `Google` for it.

Comment: @JohnConde Now what to say to the respondents?

Comment: If you don't show any code, we have to assume you haven't made an effort. And most of the people here are asking for help with their code. Not for us to write their code. Big difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables using your `Clinic_has_Doctor` to connect the `Clinic` to the `Doctor` table:

```
select c.id ClinicId,
  c.name ClinicName,
  d.id DoctorId,
  d.name Doctor_name
from clinic c
inner join Clinic_has_Doctor cd
  on c.id = cd.clinic_id
inner join doctor d
  on cd.Doctor_id = d.id
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax then here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

I used an `INNER JOIN` in the query which will return all `Clinics` and the doctors that are associated with them.

If you want to return a list of `Clinics` even if there is no doctor associated then you will use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select c.id ClinicId,
  c.name ClinicName,
  d.id DoctorId,
  d.name Doctor_name
from clinic c
left join Clinic_has_Doctor cd
  on c.id = cd.clinic_id
left join doctor d
  on cd.Doctor_id = d.id
```

Comment: why join? any reason or constraints for this ?

Comment: @Arpit They have a join table `Clinic_has_Doctor` that assigned the doctor to the clinic which is what they are asking for.

Comment: oh! +1 for the link this is what i want to clear from last 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like this:

```
select clinic_has_doctor.clinic_id
     , clinic.clinic_name
     , clinic_has_doctor.doctor_id
     , doctor.doctor_name
from   clinic_has_Doctor 
join   clinic 
on     clinic.id=clinic_has_Doctor.clinic_id
join   doctor
on     doctor.id=clinic_has_Doctor.doctor_id
```

Comment: @JulienPalard Don't remember; I'm mostly self-taught.  Putting commas at the beginning of lists makes it easier (for me) to make changes.  I can insert or delete the entire line.  Just a habit, same as my peculiar indentation style.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked, but I had to mark @bluefeet's answer as the accepted one as it's simpler (even though only in typing side).